# Adding footnotes to table with superscripting numbers in row names - rmd

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

As I use `pack_rows()`, `str_replace(df, "S2", "$^{2}$")` isn't working in `asis_output()`. Could you please provide an answer for fixing this.
I add the reproducible code below,

```
df <- data.frame(city=c("NYCHACK IT1 N (%)","LA","CHI S2 N (%)","MIA"),
                 score=sample(1:100, 4, replace=T))

output <- df %>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = T, longtable = TRUE, align = 'l',
        caption = "caption", linesep = "") %>%
  kable_styling(position = "left", latex_options = 
                c("scale_down","hold_position"), font_size = 8) %>%
  pack_rows(index = c(" " = 1,
                      "Header 1" = 2, 
                      "Header 2" = 1)) %>%
  footnote(number = c("Footnote 1",
                      "Footnote 2"), threeparttable = TRUE)

asis_output(str_replace(output, "IT1", "$^{1}$"),
                   str_replace(output, "S2", "$^{2}$"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `pack_rows`. To make your code work you have to do `str_replace(output, "IT1", "$^{1}$") |> str_replace("S2", "$^{2}$")`, i.e. pass the result after adding the first footnote symbol into the second `str_replace`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2024-02-24"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(stringr)
```

```{r}
df <- data.frame(
  city = c("NYCHACK IT1 N (%)", "LA", "CHI S2 N (%)", "MIA"),
  score = sample(1:100, 4, replace = T)
)
```

```{r}
output <- df %>%
  kable("latex",
    booktabs = T, longtable = TRUE, align = "l",
    caption = "caption", linesep = ""
  ) %>%
  kable_styling(
    position = "left", latex_options =
      c("scale_down", "hold_position"), font_size = 8
  ) %>%
  pack_rows(index = c(
    " " = 1,
    "Header 1" = 2,
    "Header 2" = 1
  )) %>%
  footnote(number = c(
    "Footnote 1",
    "Footnote 2"
  ), threeparttable = TRUE)

asis_output(
  str_replace(output, "IT1", "$^{1}$") |> 
    str_replace("S2", "$^{2}$")
)
```
````

[image]